# How do I perform an array insert into a junction table when the parent tables' values are all stored into an array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-insert

I am using postgresql.
So, imagine I have 3 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE article (
article_id BIGSERIAL,
article_name VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(article_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
tag_id VARCHAR(30)[] NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(tag_id)
);
```

And the junction table:

```
CREATE TABLE article_tags (
tag_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
article_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(tag_id) REFERENCES tags(tag_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(article_id) REFERENCES article(article_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (article_id, tag_id)
```

So within my tags table I have an entry that is an array of all possible tags i.e.

```
tag_id
______
{tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4}
```

When I try to perform an insert within article_tags of any of the individual/combinations of tags i.e. (assume an article with an ID of 1 exists)

```
INSERT INTO article_tags (article_id, tag_id) VALUES (1, '{tag4}');
OR
INSERT INTO article_tags (article_id, tag_id) VALUES (1, '{tag4, tag3}');
```

I encounter the error

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "article_tags" violates foreign key constraint "article_tags_tag_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (tag_id)=({tag4}) is not present in table "tags". / DETAIL:  Key (tag_id)=({tag4, tag3}) is not present in table "tags".
```

Is there a way to make it so that the insert considers all the values within the primary key's array (the tag_id) to perform the insert? If it's due to a table structuring error, is there a better way to structure the tables so that I am able to insert any value of tag to article_tags that is present within tags(tag_id)'s array without inserting all possible permutations of tags to tags(tag_id), which would take quite a bit but would allow it to work.

If I instead did an insert of exactly that array, it would work

```
INSERT INTO article_tags (article_id, tag_id) VALUES (1, '{tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4}');
```

but I do not wish to create every single permutation of tags unless it is required.

Comment: Wich DB are you using, Mysql or Postgresql?? Please tag correctly

Comment: @nacho I apologise- I am using postgresql.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY(tag_id)` makes the **whole** array the primary key. So any foreign key value must contain **exactly** the same values in the exactly the same order. You can't have foreign keys on individual array elements. You need to properly normalize your data model if you want that. The table `tags` should not use an array to begin with. Create one row per tag if you really need a foreign key

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi, thank you!

Beforehand, I had it set to where each tag had its own row within the table and the table did not utilize an array- but at that point I was only able to make it work by having each article only be attached to a single tag / by doing inserts one by one, and I was unsure on how to perform multiple inserts for a single array of values. i.e. If my frontend selector sent in the code as multiple tags i.e. [tag2, tag3, tag4], how would I structure my inserts so that each tag would be inserted within the same query when using a normalized array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the normalized structure where each tag has its own row; as you indicated you had "beforehand". Postgres provides a veritable cornucopia (lots) of [functions dealing with arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html). To attach an article to each tag from an array you want `UNNEST`, to rebuild the *article, array of tags* structure use `ARRAY AGG`.

```
  insert into article_tags(article_id, tag_id) 
     select a.article_id, t.tag_id
       from (select article_id
               from article
              where article_name = <article name> 
             ) a
      cross join (select tag_id 
                    from tags 
                   where tag_name in (select unnest ( <tags array >)) 
                 ) t 
      on conflict (article_id, tag_id) do nothing ;
```

--- Rebuild Article_Name, Tag_Array

```
select a.article_name, array_agg(t.tag_name order by t.tag_name) 
  from article_tags  ats 
  join article       a  on (a.article_id = ats.article_id)
  join tags          t  on (t.tag_id = ats.tag_id)
 group by article_name;
```

See the [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b15b92dabc97407899c51a4238b96a6d) for using them. The example constructs a stored procedure to handle creating entries in the 3 tables at once. But the statements within it can be run independently with minor modification to parameter passing.